# How to loop a one-sample t-test over a combination of variables and treatments?

Tags: python, loops, scipy, statistics, iteration

I am trying to loop a one-sample t-test over a large number of observations using scipy's '**stats.ttest_1samp**'.

To each observation corresponds a treatment and a variable.

Here is the structure of the dataset:

```
observations = {'treatment': ['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],
          'var1': ['50','50','50','60','60','60','70','70','70'],
          'var2': ['10','10','10','15','15','15','20','20','20']
          }
```

I need to apply a one-sample t-test to each combination 'treatment & variable' (for example 'treatment A & var1', 'treatment C & var2', etc.), and to compare it to a corresponding known mean (mu), located in another dataframe.

The dataframe mu containing the known means is as follows:

```
mu = {'treatment': ['A','B','C'],
   'var1': ['55', '60', '75'],
   'var2': ['15', '10', '25']
   }
```

The final output should return the results of each t-test in a dataframe having the same structure as mu.

I am new to python, and despite my searches on loops and iteration, this is beyond my level...
Hope you can help and that my question is clear!

Answer (score 0):

The way to access the lists within the dictionary `observation` is by using `observation['listName']` e.g. `observation['treatment']`.

It looks like the lists are already sorted, so using a `for-loop` or a `while-loop` with an iterator would let you pair the treatments with the variables by appending the corresponding values to a sort of structure.

You can then compare the values for each treatment with the mu.

Because the lenght of the mu list is 3 and the treatment lists have a length of 9, you could use the `math.ceil` function to iterate over both list lenghts in a single loop.

it would look something like this:

```
import math

arrayTreatments = observations['treatment']
arrayVar1 = observations['var1']
arrayVar2 = observations['var2']

muTreatments = mu['treatment']
muVar1 = mu['var1']
muVar2 = mu['var2']

for i in range(len(array)):
  j = math.ceil(i/3)
  if arrayVar1[i] == muVar1[j]:
     #the treatment at position i in the observationTreatment equals mu for var1
     #add it to a structure
```